# Random dictionary searches which never returns same item twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, search

Is there a way when asking the program to chose a random entry from a dictionary of key-value entries is there a way that once every entry has been picked once the program will let the user know that all entries have been picked and then stop, ultimately only allowing each entry to be picked once so, if there are only 3 entries the program will only run 3 times and if there are 100 entries it will run 100 times and so on? New to python coding so please bear with me.

```
from random import *
def show_keys():
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
    """
    random_key = choice(list(keys))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(keys [random_key])




# Set up the keys


keys = {'key1':'definition1',
        'key2':'definition2',
        'key3':'definition3'}



# The loop

exit = False
while not exit:
user_input = input('Enter s to show a key, or q to quit: ')
if user_input == 'q':
    exit = True
elif user_input == 's':
    show_keys()

else:
    print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

Comment: put all keys into a list, random.shuffle() the list, pop the last one till empty.

Comment: you could get all the keys, put them in a list, shuffle the list and then pick them in order from the list

Comment: You should add some code to your question. People are more likely to respond that way.

Comment: @PatrickArtner would be more efficient to do a `random.choice(...)`.

Comment: @Err depends. Assuming you want to "empty" the dict with 3 to 1000 keys: shuffling a list of all keys _once_ and then popping from it till empty is less costly then doing choice() 1000 times and list.remove() 1000 times. If you can delete keys from the dict itself, using choice from the dict and deleting the key afterwards is better because no list needed - advatage of the list is: dict is unchanged and you can "rerun" your game by refilling the list

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys from the dictionary, select random elements from that list, get the dictionary entry and remove the key from the list subsequently.

```
import random

dictionary = {
    'one': '1',
    'two': '2',
    'three': '3'
}

# getting list of keys from dictionary
keys = list(dictionary.keys())
print(keys)

# picking random elemt from list
elem = random.choice(keys)
print(elem, dictionary.get(elem))

# remove an element from a list
keys.remove(elem)
print(keys)
```

Comment: @Redunited comment above not here. Just edit your question and paste the code. Someone will edit it for you if you get it wrong but the code should be in a triple ``` block (the key below `esc`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to collect which keys you aready asked for.
Provide the set and the dict to the function that asks for a definition so it can add a new key to it - do not use globals.
Loop until either no more guesses possible (`len(already)==len(data)`) and handle that case or until user wants to quit:

```
from random import choice   # do not import ALL - just what you need

def show_keys(d,a):  # provide data and already used key set
    """ Show the user a random key and ask them
        to define it. Show the definition
        when the user presses return.    
        d : your dict of keys and definitions
        a : a set of already used keys
    """
    # choice only for those keys that are not yet used
    random_key = choice( [k for k in d if k not in a] )

    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(d [random_key])

    # add used key to a - you could ask (y/n) if the definition was correct
    # and only then add the key - if wrong it has a chance of being asked again
    a.add(random_key)

# Set up the data with keys and defs

data = {'key1':'definition1',
        'key2':'definition2',
        'key3':'definition3'}

# set up already seen keys 
already = set()

# The loop 
while True:  # loop until break

    # nothing more to guess
    if len(already)==len(data):
        y = input("Game over. Play again? [y, ]").lower()
        if y=="y":
            # reset set of seen stuff to empty set()
            already = set()
        else:
            break

    user_input = input('Enter s to show a key, or q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
    elif user_input == 's': 
        # provide data and already to the function, don't use globals
        show_keys(data,already)
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```

---

Alternativly: create a shuffled list and use that:

```
from random import shuffle

data = {'key1':'definition1',
        'key2':'definition2',
        'key3':'definition3'}

already = set()

shuffled = list(data.items())
shuffle(shuffled)

# The loop 
while shuffled:
    user_input = input('Enter s to show a key, or q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'q':
        break
    elif user_input == 's':
        key,value = shuffled.pop()
        print('Define: ', key)
        input('Press return to see the definition')
        print(value) 
    else:
        print('You need to enter either q or s.')
```